# Get the taxonomy of a post hierarchically

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, order, hierarchical

I would like to get all the taxonomy of one post (in a loop), hierarchically.
Example I have those taxonomies, and the ID of the tax in bracket.

```
Tax1(1)
-Tax2(3)
--Tax3(2)
```

I would like to gather them, in an array maybe, in this order.
Right now I manage to get an array of those 3, but the order is wrong.
I can't order it by id, since the ID are not ordered at first. I can't also order it by name and slug. (Names of my current taxonomies are not Tax1, Tax2...)

The code I have at the moment is

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'term_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
$productcategories = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'guide_type', $args);
```